# Correct way to shard a collection and how to interpret the results

Tags: mongodb, sharding, chunks, replicaset

I have a collection with elements of this type and I'd like to shard on the _id attribute (I don't know if it is a good idea, it's just to check if it is balanced"):
[image]

The collection has these number of elements:
[image]

These are the operation I did, but I do not understand if it is balanced or not and how many elements are there in each replica. The numbers "512" were there even before I sharded the collection, moreover I don't see any reference on the number of chunks.[image]
[image]
[image]

Edit: this is the new sharding status:

```
  --- Sharding Status --- 
  sharding version: {
    "_id" : 1,
    "minCompatibleVersion" : 5,
    "currentVersion" : 6,
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("61070038743c28b844e57bb6")
  }
  shards:
        {  "_id" : "mongors1",  "host" : "mongors1/mongors1n1:27018,mongors1n2:27018,mongors1n3:27018",  "state" : 1,  "topologyTime" : Timestamp(1627848830, 1) }
        {  "_id" : "mongors2",  "host" : "mongors2/mongors2n1:27018,mongors2n2:27018,mongors2n3:27018",  "state" : 1,  "topologyTime" : Timestamp(1627848839, 1) }
  active mongoses:
        "5.0.1" : 2
  autosplit:
        Currently enabled: yes
  balancer:
        Currently enabled: yes
        Currently running: yes
        Collections with active migrations: 
                maadbProject_id.words started at Mon Aug 02 2021 11:05:15 GMT+0200 (CEST)
        Failed balancer rounds in last 5 attempts: 0
        Migration results for the last 24 hours: 
                513 : Success
                2 : Failed with error 'aborted', from mongors1 to mongors2
  databases:
        {  "_id" : "config",  "primary" : "config",  "partitioned" : true }
                config.system.sessions
                        shard key: { "_id" : 1 }
                        unique: false
                        balancing: true
                        chunks:
                                mongors1    512
                                mongors2    512
                        too many chunks to print, use verbose if you want to force print
        {  "_id" : "maadbProject_id",  "primary" : "mongors2",  "partitioned" : true,  "version" : {  "uuid" : UUID("e7c4d27d-bef1-45b3-99fe-600aa3913788"),  "timestamp" : Timestamp(1627854766, 1),  "lastMod" : 1 } }
                maadbProject_id.words
                        shard key: { "_id" : 1 }
                        unique: false
                        balancing: true
                        chunks:
                                mongors1    1
                                mongors2    5
                        { "_id" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "_id" : ObjectId("610718944c6f5d02bc26e600") } on : mongors1 Timestamp(2, 0) 
                        { "_id" : ObjectId("610718944c6f5d02bc26e600") } -->> { "_id" : ObjectId("610718c34c6f5d02bc2e8721") } on : mongors2 Timestamp(3, 0) 
                        { "_id" : ObjectId("610718c34c6f5d02bc2e8721") } -->> { "_id" : ObjectId("61071f28b6f44b3740060215") } on : mongors2 Timestamp(1, 3) 
                        { "_id" : ObjectId("61071f28b6f44b3740060215") } -->> { "_id" : ObjectId("61071f29b6f44b374009d2a6") } on : mongors2 Timestamp(1, 4) 
                        { "_id" : ObjectId("61071f29b6f44b374009d2a6") } -->> { "_id" : ObjectId("6107a632425993445c255f5e") } on : mongors2 Timestamp(1, 5) 
                        { "_id" : ObjectId("6107a632425993445c255f5e") } -->> { "_id" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : mongors2 Timestamp(1, 6)
```

Comment: Please don't paste images, use formated text.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that collection is now sharded.  I'd copy paste the text from the response that shows it, but that's an image.

That shows that the collection you sharded now has 1 chunk, so all of the data still resides on a single shard.

The default maximum chunk size in MongoDB is 64MB, it will usually split when a chunk contain between 32 and 64MB.

It will balancer according to chunk count, without regard to number of documents or total size.

If you want to exercise the balancer, either add more data so the auto splitter creates more chunks, manually split that chunk, or shard an empty collection using a hashed shard key.

Comment: Thank you for your exhaustive answer. I updated the question after inserting some new data, but now I have 1 chunk in the first shard and 5 in the second one. Does it means that it is unbalanced, doesn't it? Shouldn't have it auto-balance the new data? Are there ways I can manually balance it?

Comment: Balancing is not instantaneous, it will need to copy all of the data for one chunk to the new shard, delete it from the old shard, the repeat.  The fact that 1 chunk now appears on the other shard means the balancer is working, check again after a while to see if any more have migrated.