# How to balance a sharded collection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, sharding, chunks

I have a collection called "words", inside my maadbProject_id database on MongoDB, and as you can see I have 1 chunk in the first shard and 5 in the second one. Does it means that it is unbalanced, doesn't it? Shouldn't have it auto-balance the data? Are there ways I can manually balance it?

```
  --- Sharding Status --- 
  sharding version: {
    "_id" : 1,
    "minCompatibleVersion" : 5,
    "currentVersion" : 6,
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("61070038743c28b844e57bb6")
  }
  shards:
        {  "_id" : "mongors1",  "host" : "mongors1/mongors1n1:27018,mongors1n2:27018,mongors1n3:27018",  "state" : 1,  "topologyTime" : Timestamp(1627848830, 1) }
        {  "_id" : "mongors2",  "host" : "mongors2/mongors2n1:27018,mongors2n2:27018,mongors2n3:27018",  "state" : 1,  "topologyTime" : Timestamp(1627848839, 1) }
  active mongoses:
        "5.0.1" : 2
  autosplit:
        Currently enabled: yes
  balancer:
        Currently enabled: yes
        Currently running: yes
        Collections with active migrations: 
                maadbProject_id.words started at Mon Aug 02 2021 11:05:15 GMT+0200 (CEST)
        Failed balancer rounds in last 5 attempts: 0
        Migration results for the last 24 hours: 
                513 : Success
                2 : Failed with error 'aborted', from mongors1 to mongors2
  databases:
        {  "_id" : "config",  "primary" : "config",  "partitioned" : true }
                config.system.sessions
                        shard key: { "_id" : 1 }
                        unique: false
                        balancing: true
                        chunks:
                                mongors1    512
                                mongors2    512
                        too many chunks to print, use verbose if you want to force print
        {  "_id" : "maadbProject_id",  "primary" : "mongors2",  "partitioned" : true,  "version" : {  "uuid" : UUID("e7c4d27d-bef1-45b3-99fe-600aa3913788"),  "timestamp" : Timestamp(1627854766, 1),  "lastMod" : 1 } }
                maadbProject_id.words
                        shard key: { "_id" : 1 }
                        unique: false
                        balancing: true
                        chunks:
                                mongors1    1
                                mongors2    5
                        { "_id" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "_id" : ObjectId("610718944c6f5d02bc26e600") } on : mongors1 Timestamp(2, 0) 
                        { "_id" : ObjectId("610718944c6f5d02bc26e600") } -->> { "_id" : ObjectId("610718c34c6f5d02bc2e8721") } on : mongors2 Timestamp(3, 0) 
                        { "_id" : ObjectId("610718c34c6f5d02bc2e8721") } -->> { "_id" : ObjectId("61071f28b6f44b3740060215") } on : mongors2 Timestamp(1, 3) 
                        { "_id" : ObjectId("61071f28b6f44b3740060215") } -->> { "_id" : ObjectId("61071f29b6f44b374009d2a6") } on : mongors2 Timestamp(1, 4) 
                        { "_id" : ObjectId("61071f29b6f44b374009d2a6") } -->> { "_id" : ObjectId("6107a632425993445c255f5e") } on : mongors2 Timestamp(1, 5) 
                        { "_id" : ObjectId("6107a632425993445c255f5e") } -->> { "_id" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : mongors2 Timestamp(1, 6)
```

I repeated the process (this time with less data) and changing the key, this is the output of `db.getSiblingDB("maadbProject_id").words.getShardDistribution()`:

```
    mongos> db.getSiblingDB("maadbProject_id").words.getShardDistribution()

Shard mongors2 at mongors2/mongors2n1:27018,mongors2n2:27018,mongors2n3:27018
 data : 78.18MiB docs : 1408521 chunks : 0
 estimated data per chunk : 0B
 estimated docs per chunk : 0

Shard mongors1 at mongors1/mongors1n1:27018,mongors1n2:27018,mongors1n3:27018
 data : 0B docs : 0 chunks : 0
 estimated data per chunk : 0B
 estimated docs per chunk : 0

Totals
 data : 78.18MiB docs : 1408521 chunks : 0
 Shard mongors2 contains 100% data, 100% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 58B
 Shard mongors1 contains 0% data, 0% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 0B
```

This is the new sharding status:

```
mongos> sh.status()
--- Sharding Status --- 
  sharding version: {
    "_id" : 1,
    "minCompatibleVersion" : 5,
    "currentVersion" : 6,
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("6107da8b77c51eb546ef6cbe")
  }
  shards:
        {  "_id" : "mongors1",  "host" : "mongors1/mongors1n1:27018,mongors1n2:27018,mongors1n3:27018",  "state" : 1,  "topologyTime" : Timestamp(1627904682, 2) }
        {  "_id" : "mongors2",  "host" : "mongors2/mongors2n1:27018,mongors2n2:27018,mongors2n3:27018",  "state" : 1,  "topologyTime" : Timestamp(1627904690, 2) }
  active mongoses:
        "5.0.1" : 2
  autosplit:
        Currently enabled: yes
  balancer:
        Currently enabled: yes
        Currently running: no
        Failed balancer rounds in last 5 attempts: 0
        Migration results for the last 24 hours: 
                512 : Success
                2 : Failed with error 'aborted', from mongors1 to mongors2
  databases:
        {  "_id" : "config",  "primary" : "config",  "partitioned" : true }
                config.system.sessions
                        shard key: { "_id" : 1 }
                        unique: false
                        balancing: true
                        chunks:
                                mongors1    512
                                mongors2    512
                        too many chunks to print, use verbose if you want to force print
        {  "_id" : "maadbProject-id",  "primary" : "mongors2",  "partitioned" : true,  "version" : {  "uuid" : UUID("65f1bd02-06d6-4a22-a676-3d8d42ccf559"),  "timestamp" : Timestamp(1627904796, 2),  "lastMod" : 1 } }
        {  "_id" : "maadbProject_id",  "primary" : "mongors2",  "partitioned" : true,  "version" : {  "uuid" : UUID("bf722f4e-848e-4245-af56-04c0778fa333"),  "timestamp" : Timestamp(1627907989, 1),  "lastMod" : 1 } }
                maadbProject_id.words
                        shard key: { "feeling" : 1 }
                        unique: false
                        balancing: true
                        chunks:
                                mongors1    1
                                mongors2    3
                        { "feeling" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "feeling" : "Anger" } on : mongors1 Timestamp(3, 0) 
                        { "feeling" : "Anger" } -->> { "feeling" : "Joy" } on : mongors2 Timestamp(4, 0) 
                        { "feeling" : "Joy" } -->> { "feeling" : "Sadness" } on : mongors2 Timestamp(1, 3) 
                        { "feeling" : "Sadness" } -->> { "feeling" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : mongors2 Timestamp(1, 4) 
mongos>
```

Running the command `db.getSiblingDB("maadbProject_id").words.getShardDistribution()`after a few restart of docker this is the situation:

```
mongos> db.getSiblingDB("maadbProject_id").words.getShardDistribution()

Shard mongors2 at mongors2/mongors2n1:27018,mongors2n2:27018,mongors2n3:27018
 data : 78.18MiB docs : 1408521 chunks : 0
 estimated data per chunk : 0B
 estimated docs per chunk : 0

Shard mongors1 at mongors1/mongors1n1:27018,mongors1n2:27018,mongors1n3:27018
 data : 23.79MiB docs : 424345 chunks : 0
 estimated data per chunk : 0B
 estimated docs per chunk : 0
```

How is possible that it is changing?

Comment: What do you get from `db.getSiblingDB("maadbProject_id").words.getShardDistribution()`?

Comment: According to your (same) [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68616921/correct-way-to-shard-a-collection-and-how-to-interpret-the-results) your documents are way too small. Make them bigger or add a few thousands.

Comment: Using `_id` as shard key is a poor choice, see [Choose a Shard Key](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-choose-a-shard-key/). The `_id` is a [monotonically changing](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-choose-a-shard-key/#std-label-shard-key-monotonic) key, this should be avoided.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I updated the question with more details

Comment: The `getShardDistribution()` output does not match the `sh.status()`. Compare the number of chunks per shard (1&3 vs. 0)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I updated the question. Now the command shows some documents, but I didn't insert any new data. How is possible that it is changing?

Comment: That's normal, the balancer is not a permanently running process. Shifting the data from one shard to the other takes some time.

Comment: Check the logs for chunk move messages to see if anything is failing.